# Call another class method inside button

Tags: java, android

I have `ContactUs.java` and `Mail.java` classes.

I want to call method from Mail class into `Contactus onclicklistner` method .

```
    package com.hesham.sams;



public class ContactusActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contactus);

    TextView subjectTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subjectTxt);
    TextView emailTxtus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.emailTxtus);
    final TextView messageTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTxt);
    Button lButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);

     String hh =  messageTxt.getText().toString();

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "extrafine.ttf");  
    subjectTxt.setTypeface(font);
    emailTxtus.setTypeface(font);
    messageTxt.setTypeface(font);

    String array_spinner[];
    array_spinner=new String[3];
    array_spinner[0]="general";
    array_spinner[1]="quisiton";
    array_spinner[2]="suggsution";

     Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(      android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.spinner1 );
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


    //ArrayAdapter adapter = new   ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
    //adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.special_spinner_dropdown);   
    //s.setAdapter(adapter);




        // send Botton
    //public string hesham(){


        lButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        // here is the proeblem 
                        Mail.send();

                    }
                });




               // ignoring 
              final class SpinnerActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                            int pos, long id) {
                        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
                        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
                        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        // Another interface callback
                    }







            } 

}// end of on create

                } // end of class
```

second class :

```
  package com.hesham.sams;

 import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
 import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
 import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

 public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 

  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  /*public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } */

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
}
```

note: I can't use extend because each one of this class has already defend to extends another classes . 
and do you know java can't extends two classes at same time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if the classes are static or not. If they are static you can just use them inline `Mail.MethodName();`

If they are not static then you need to create an instance of them first

```
Mail mc = new Mail();

mc.MethodName();
```

Comment: no it's not static i have but the anouther class static but there is a lot of errors ,, and i have put instance but did not work .

Comment: You need to post all of your code and clean up your question. If you don't someone will down vote this for sure.

Comment: not worked :  lButton.setOnClickListener(mm.send()); // mm is object of Mail class .

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it by not using an annonymous class. Create a full class, and give it a constructor that takes a reference to whatever data it needs.  Store that in member variables of the class.  Then in the onClick, you can reference that member variable.  When you call setOnClickListener, just pass it a new instance of that class.